# Defining SMARTS reaction template

Tags: cheminformatics

I want to have a reaction template involves combination of 2 radicals such as this one `O=C1CCC(=O)[N]1.[H]>>[H]N1C(=O)C([H])([H])C([H])([H])C1=O`.

A generic reaction template would involve [N]  (with 1 radical electron and 2 unpaired electrons) attached to any 2 groups (or in a ring) and a radical [H] and these 2 get combined. So I tried something simple like this `*-[N]-*.[H]>>*-[NH]-*`  as a SMARTS template but I didn't get what I want.

I would really appreciate it if you could help with this specific example and perhaps also provide some info (links or keywords) regarding this topic! (I have checked out the Daylight website https://www.daylight.com/cheminformatics/ but it's not clear at all)

Code sample

```
from rdkit import Chem

first_radical = 'O=C1CCC(=O)[N]1'
second_radical = '[H]'

rxn = Chem.AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts('*-[N]-*.[H]>>*-[NH]-*')

ps = rxn.RunReactants((Chem.MolFromSmiles(first_radical),Chem.MolFromSmiles(second_radical)))
print(Chem.MolToSmiles(ps[0][0]))
```

Desired result: `[H]N1C(=O)C([H])([H])C([H])([H])C1=O`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to know. What do you mean by "I didn't get what I want"?

Comment: Hi @GeoffHutchison I've updated the question to be more specific!

Comment: I'm not an expert at `RunReactants` but I notice that you're not defining atom mappings. If you look at examples, e.g., the "thiazole synthesis" you'll see that you need to give atom classes in both the reactants and products to indicate which atoms go where. It doesn't just "guess" that your `[H]` radical goes into your product. You have to tell it.